# Rearranging algebraic formula when subject appears twice and is squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am unsure how to tackle making $t$ the subject of this formula

$D = ut + kt^2$

Because it appears twice and is squared, does this mean I have to factorise quadratically? I have tried but how is this possible when you only have algebra coefficients? Also surely if it was factorised into 2 brackets then you still wouldn't be able to single out the subject onto one side, so I guess you would have to factorise it into one bracket?

Please can someone make sense of this for me, explaining simply?
Thankyou

Comment: Sorry; what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: making $t$ the subject so like $t = ...$ by making it appear on its own on one side

Comment: Complete the squares.  $kt^2+ut=k(t^2+\frac ukt)=k\left(t^2+\frac uk t+\frac {u^2}{4k^2}-\frac {u^2}{4k^2}\right)=k(t+\frac {u}{2k})^2-k\times \frac {u^2}{4k^2}$

Comment: You could also use the quadratic formula after subtracting D on both sides.

Comment: @lulu so afterwards does the rearranged formula $= D$ so then you can rearrange to make $t$ appear on one side? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  As has been remarked, this is just the same as using the quadratic formula.   In fact, this is how the quadratic formula is demonstrated.

Comment: @lulu ok I think I worked out an answer but I'm not sure if it seems right $t = sqrt (D/K +u^2/4k^2) - u/2k$  Sorry I don't know how to correctly format these things

Comment: Well, at a minimum your expression should allow both signs for the square root.  But let's check your expression using the quadratic formula.  Rearrange the original to get $kt^2+ut-D=0$.  The quadratic formula then tells us that $t=\frac {-u\pm \sqrt {u^2+4kD}}{2k}$.  Can you check that this is the same as your expression (other than the signs of the square root)?

Comment: @lulu oh yes I forgot about the plus minus symbol. Apart from that I think they are the same, except I'm not sure how can you $\frac{\sqrt{u^2+4kD}} {2k}$? Do you make the bottom into $\sqrt{4k^2}$ but then how do you divide the two surds, are you allowed to divide each of the terms under the ${\sqrt{u^2+4kD}}$ by the $\sqrt{4k^2}$ separately? I don't get why because we have never been taught this..

Comment: If you have something like $\frac {\sqrt a}b$, you can write $b=\sqrt {b^2}$ (at least if $b>0)$ and then $\frac {\sqrt a}b=\frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt {b^2}}=\sqrt {\frac {a}{b^2}}$.

Comment: @ lulu ok I see, and for if there were 2 terms under the nominator $\sqrt{}$ I would be able to divide them separately by the denominator surd? so $\frac{\sqrt{a+b}}{\sqrt{c}} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}}$ is this allowed? Thanks